# How to set my ESPG to geography POINT in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, table, geography-data-type

I'm trying to create a table into my PostGIS 2.3

```
CREATE TABLE destinations (
    id          serial                      PRIMARY KEY,
    sector      integer                     REFERENCES sectors(id),
    name        varchar(64)                 NOT NULL,
    location    geography(POINT, 25831)     NOT NULL,
    authcode    varchar(16)                 NOT NULL
);
```

I specify the SRS *ESPG:25831* that I'm using to the `location` field, but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
LINE 6: location    geography(POINT,25831)      NOT NULL,
```

I've checked the `spatial_ref_sys` table and `25831` is there. I also have enabled the PostGIS extension. In fact, my query works if I remove the SRS:

```
location    geography(POINT)     NOT NULL,
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a projection, you have to use the **geometry** type instead.
The geography type is only valid for coordinates in WGS 84 GCS.

More information can be found here:

[Difference between geometry and geography type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26082/what-is-the-difference-between-geometric-and-geographic-columns)

[Pros and Cons of geometry and geography type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types)

Try

```
location    geometry(POINT, 25831)
```