# gdal_translate made wrong tranforms

Tags: gdal, utm

I have a geotiff file in UTM and units in meters. I used gdal_translate with this command :

`gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 -a_srs EPSG:4326 old.tif new.tif`

gdalinfo on new.tif shows that the file units are in degrees while the data (corners,origin ...etc) are given in meters which is wrong.
Is it possible to reverse/correct this action (on the new file) so I can get the file with either UTM in meters or go on and make the file in "real" degrees because I deleted the original file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be getting confused between a geographic coordinate system, which is what EPSG:4326 represents, and a projected coordinate system. Looking at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/is-wgs84-itself-a-coordinate-reference-system/23700#23700) might help.

To recover the right projection parameters in this case, you need to know which zone your data is in, then use the `-a_srs` parameter with either `EPSG:327xx` for the southern hemisphere or `EPSG:326xx` for the northern hemisphere, where `xx` is the UTM zone.

Answer (score 1):

Praobably what you want is [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html). It is the right tool to make projection transforms, indicating the source (s_srs) and the target (t_srs) CRS.
The a_srs option in gdal_translate overrides the Geotiff projection, it doesn't transform it.