# Difference between CRS (Coordinate Reference System) and SRS (Spatial Reference System)

Tags: coordinate-system

I could see that CRS and SRS are referred as different components in this question
[Is WGS84 itself a Coordinate Reference System?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/is-wgs84-itself-a-coordinate-reference-system?rq=1)

Could anyone please explain whether CRS and SRS are same or different?

Comment: @PolyGeo: Apologies for not adding it. I have updated it now.

Comment: I think water is mudded on the topic.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/is-wgs84-itself-a-coordinate-reference-system#:~:text=It%20is%20made%20up%20of,refer%20to%20three%20different%20things!

Answer (score 16):

As of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system):

> A spatial reference system (SRS) or coordinate reference system (CRS)

They are synonyms.

What you see in the linked article is the difference between the **reference-ellipsoid** which is *part* of the **spatial reference system**. In your case `WGS84` is just an ellipsoid, which itself more or less accurately describes the earth. However without any grid there's no way to say where on this sphere a given point is because you don't have any information on where is zero, in which direction is north, how long is a unit. Thus you also need some *coordinate system* which is the second part of the CRS.

However there exist a bunch of reference-ellipsoids which are almost allways used with only one single coordinate system, like WGS84 is allways used in combination with geographic coordinates having a latitude and a longitude. However you could also express a location based on that ellipsoid in metric coordinates also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I have seen the Wikipedia article but was confused by this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/is-wgs84-itself-a-coordinate-reference-system?rq=1. Please correct me if I'm understanding it wrongly.