# Leaflet Tiling with epsg4326?

Tags: leaflet, epsg

i'm using leaflet to render a map on my site.

The problem is, i use mongoDB to perform some geospatial queries serverside, which use as standard the infamous epsg4326.

It appears that on leaflet there is support for this format, though i wasn't able to find a tile server with this specification.

Can anyone suggest one ?

Comment: You would probably be interested in this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198073/projections-leaflet-and-osm/198098#198098

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the data in MongoDB must be vector data right? In that case, you can keep the map in WebMercator, and just show your data on top of it, as a Vector (i.e. GeoJSON, etc) Layer.

Comment: problem is i'm using geojson documents in mongo and geospatial query to retrive data, but the geospatial queries use as projection this format, while on leaflet even if there's support for epsg4326, the tile servers i've found only serve 3857...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Yes, most tile provider use 3857 but, 4326 is also native supported by leaflet.

Before you asked question did you try retrieved data from mongo to use with leaflet? As far as I know it's shouldn't be a problem. When you add geojson with points in 4326 leaflet will internally reproject them to 3857.

Comment: yeah, deforming them. i've done it. i need leaflet to not projects the points at all