# WGS 1984 Geographic Coordinate System, Version 2 vs WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I'm fairly new to GIS, and wondering if someone can tell me if there is a difference between WGS 1984 Geographic Coordinate System, Version 2 and WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)?

Are they just different names for the same exact thing?

Can someone tell me if they have different WKIDs/ ESPG numbers?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but this may help:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet .  In particular, a lot of online map services use two coordinate system - a projected coordinate system for the map being displayed, and a geographic coordinate system for the numerical coordinates (eg, mouse position, features location).  This link explains that issue clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out what you mean by 'WGS 1984 Geographic Coordinate System, Version 2'. There's no such coordinate reference system (CRS) by that name in Esri software.

Meanwhile, a long time ago in a software not so far away, we added ESRI::102113, "WGS 1984 Web Mercator." The name is unfortunate, because the geographic CRS used was actually a variant of WGS 1984 (EPSG::4326) in that it used a sphere with radius = 6378137.0 m. Its name is "WGS 1983 Major Auxiliary Sphere." This was prior to version 9.3.

People didn't like it because the geographic CRS *wasn't* the standard WGS84 so there were issues with having to transform from a local GeoCRS to WGS84 and then to the sphere-based WGS84. One nice thing about this definition is that it used the standard Mercator algorithm, with the sphere equations triggered by the GeoCRS.

About the same time, [EPSG](http://www.epsg.org) added a similarly designed projected CRS, EPSG::3785 (sphere-based GeoCRS).

Esri then added a new Mercator algorithm, Mercator (auxiliary sphere), which defaults to using a major aux sphere (radius = semimajor axis) and supports a few other spheres. That enabled Esri to add 102100, which uses the standard WGS84 definition, but a new Mercator algorithm.

Again, about the same time, EPSG deprecated (made obsolete) 3785 in favor of 3857, which again similarly to ESRI::102100, uses the standard WGS84, and a new Mercator algorithm.

Esri then "code-changed" 102100 to 3857 to keep up with the EPSG registry/dataset. Because older servers wouldn't understand 3857, we still often publish services with the older number, 102100.

So, all 4 of these well-known IDs: 3785, 3857, 102113, 102100 will give exactly the same results. If you unproject values from any of them, the results are EPSG::4326.

Note: EPSG randomly assigned WKIDs. They did not try to confuse people by using 3857 as a replacement for 3785. It was just weirdly random.

Disclaimer: I'm an Esri employee and am on the geodesy subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry, although I was not a member of the subcommittee until after they added 3857.

Comment: I saw it in the documentation for ArcGIS Pro. I seem to have made a mistake though. What they call WGS 1984 Geographic Coordinate System, Version 2, seems to be a tiling scheme.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to use a .TPK file to create a scene view in one of their SDKS. And what I found was that the TPKs with the WKID 102100 would work in the scene view, while those with the WKID 4326 would not. Now I see that it makes sense, given your explanation, since one is projected and the other is not. At least that's what I understand here.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense now. I've never tiled anything so hadn't run across that terminology before.

Comment: Yes, I will remember when using their SDKs with TPK files: 4326 for MapView (2D) only. 102100 for SceneView (2D and 3D).  Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer.