# XYZ FILES can't process Using Potree

Tags: xyz, potree

I try to process XYZ Files In Potree but it not works But when i try .las file it work prefectly fine

My commands line arguments

```
./PotreeConverter.exe C:/wamp64/www/PotreeConverter2/PotreeConverter_1.5_windows_x64/teknikrum_finger_a_fine.xyz -o C:/wamp64/www/PotreeConverter2/PotreeConverter_1.5_windows_x64 --generate-page pageName
```

[image: EXAMPLE HERE]

NOtE : : I Don't know actual Projection i give projection of 3857 is this the problem why it is crash **but i  think there is something else** which even Crash Output result on XYZ formats ??

Comment: Is your data actually projected?  It may need EPSG:4326 because it is just lat-lon coordinates.  It is told it is should expect projected coordinates but gets data it isn't expected and crashes due to a uncaught exception.  It is hard to know without the debug information.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet

Comment: potree  Converter  Cant Process  XYZ FILES 
Although So i convert XYZ To las  then process las file and get my desire result
Thanks A lot SIr

Comment: You might write up your own answer to this question, just a quick one and link to where if you found this out if possible.  You can get credit for your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

Potree Converter 1.5 Cannot Process XYZ FILES so we have to  convert XYZ To las using **Free OF COST Feature txt2las of [Lastools](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools)**

I process las file and get my desired result.