# Maps in Google Earth and QGIS do not match?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth

So I am plotting a path of vehicle in the water and the map in Google Earth and QGIS dont line up (atleast with either the NetCDF or the CSV file).

In QGIS everything is in WSG 84 EPSG 4326

Is there a difference between QGIS and Google Earth's coordinate systems? Do I need anything coordinate system?

Heres what I am talking about: The point in QGIS should be more to the right in the yellow part

-- Google Earth --

[image]

-- QGIS --

[image]

Comment: Have you exported the point to GE or added the OpenLayers "Google Earth" image ?

Comment: Doesn't GE use Web Mercator?

Comment: @saravanaganesh18 I downloaded the file from the web and then open it in both GE and QGIS

Comment: This article has few information which might be helpful i guess

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet