# Coordinate mismatch between Google Maps and Leaflet Using ESRI World Imagery

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, esri-geodatabase

I mark a point on Google maps and get lat, lon values. When I put those values in my code which uses Vue2leaflet and ESRI World Imagery tiles from `https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}`, the coordinates seem to differ by ~20 meters.

Are they using different projections and/or datums? As far as I can tell, both should be using EPSG:3857 so I can't tell the source of the problem.

The coordinates I get from google maps is (`lat`: 40.836566, `lon`: 29.514314)

Google maps:

[image]

Leaflet:

[image]

Comment: Try somewhere else. It might be that one of the image is not properly georeferenced

Comment: This is a duplicate of [*EPSG 3857 or 4326 for GoogleMaps, OpenStreetMap and Leaflet*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet) which is already answered.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate. The linked answer makes interesting points but doesn't explain why the two geographical coordinates don't match (or I'm missing something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aerial images are simply misaligned. This is not uncommon in rural areas, where the elevation data used for the [orthorectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto) of the aerial images differs between sources.

This can be checked by loading both Google Maps (with a bit of help from [GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/)) and the ESRI aerial imagery in the same Leaflet map, and switching between the two with a `L.Control.Layers`, e.g.:

```
var map = new L.Map('leaflet');

var mutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({type: 'satellite'}).addTo(map);
var esriAerial = L.tileLayer("https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}", {
  maxZoom: 20, maxNativeZoom: 19
});

L.control.layers({google: mutant, esri: esriAerial}, {}, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

L.marker({lat: 40.836566, lon: 29.514314}).addTo(map);
map.setView({lat: 40.836566, lon: 29.514314}, 19);
```

See a [working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UBZH033vlMbMXmpMYTqS?p=preview). Take a moment to go to another area and check the misaligment between both imagery sources: it will be different.

Comment: This really seems to be the source of the problem. Is there a mechanism to let ESRI (I think google's is the better aligned one) know of these misalignment areas so they can fix it in the future?