# Why don't OpenStreetMap building footprint shapefiles match up with Google Maps or Google Earth?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, google-maps, kml, google-earth

I've been accessing OpenStreetMap shapefiles using osmnx and then exporting those files into kml files so that I can view them on Google Earth. However, when I do so it appears that the building boundaries in the OpenStreetMap shapefiles are a bit off of what I'm seeing on Google Earth (and both of them are also different from Google Maps).

Does anybody know why this might be?

Comment: See this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388393/84870). Each aerial/satellite image has to be georeferenced, and it is not always done with the same accuracy. OSM may be based on [Bing Maps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bing_Maps), or on any other source, like a government open data, the neighbor entry level gps trace or a pure hand draw guess (ex: an expected/new development with no image yet available)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!