# When Facebook returns place long/lat, what projection do they use?

Tags: facebook

When Facebook Places Search API returns place long/lat, what coordinate system and units of measurement do they use?

According to this question,
[In what coordinate system and unit measures the coordinates returned by the Google Maps API are?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101507/in-what-coordinate-system-and-unit-measures-the-coordinates-returned-by-the-goog)

This suggests most online organizations use

> Coordinate System: WGS84, Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) - EPSG 3857
>
> Planar Units: meters

However, I would like to confirm this.

Comment: It would help if you give a sample. lat/lon is usually in degrees.

Comment: By the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search/ API is returning geographic coordinates even the example does not make sense `[latitude],[longitude]; e.g., 140.7307,-73.9918` because latitude can not be 140 degrees. Anyway, it means EPSG:4326 just check the order of the coordinates.

Comment: @user30184 it's EPSG:4326? Really? how come they aren't using web mercator?

Comment: Perhaps because lat/lon is hundreds of years older standard and used for example in any GPS device. Web Mercator is widely used for visualizing but not for data transfer. See for  example KML or GeoJSON specifications.