# distance difference in Google Earth with exported GPX or KML compared to source shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth

I've converted a shapefile (points) to KML with QGIS.  Points in the shapefile are within 100m distance from each other.  When I measure it in Google Earth, the distance changes to 80m. The same happens with the created GPX file. Why is this?

My original shapefile was created in WGS84/UTM Zone 20S because I needed to work with the metric system. I'm working with data belonging to an area no larger than 6 square kilometers. As to avoid the problem I am having now, I reprojected it to WGS84 (EPSG 4326) by "saving as" and changing its SRC before I then created the KML and GPX. Both KML and GPX show the same surface, the difference comes along with the shapefile.

Sample coordinates are:

```
    id  lat long
POINT(-61.82795607536099425 -37.83722374457502724)  
POINT(-61.82861595101069696 -37.83772772712714527)  
POINT(-61.82724009148368083 -37.83767676392982793)  
POINT(-61.8278967620074269 -37.83817748597036257)
```

Comment: What projection/coordinate system is your original shapefile in? You may be getting odd results if you are trying to do a planar measurement on geodetic data (flat surface vs. curved surface).

Comment: Following on what Evil Genius said, KML is supposed to have a standard projection (EPSG:4326), so if your GPS data is using a different projection and you haven't reprojected when creating the KML, the resulting file won't load in the right place. [Related question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/what-is-the-difference-between-wgs84-and-epsg4326) (along with all the Related questions *there*).

Comment: My original shapefile was created in WGS84/UTM Zone 20S because i needed to work with metric system.  As to avoid the problem i am having now, i reproyected it to WGS84 (EPSG 4326) before i created KML and GPX. Both, KML and GPX show the same surface, the difference comes along with the shapefile.  Thank you both. Please continue with your opinions.

Comment: It may then be a function of what @EvilGenius said - your original data was in a projected CRS, and Google Earth uses a geographic CRS. I'm not a projections expert so I can't say right off. I'll edit your tags a bit and see if that doesn't attract one of them. You may want to edit your question to say exactly *how* you reprojected, as that may be relevant.

Comment: Also, since you are using UTM, is all of your data within the zone? UTM has more distortion further away from the center of the zone. Some overlap is possible, but that may also be part of the problem if your points are actually in zone 19S or 21S.

Comment: Evil Genius, all my data is within zone 20S. I´m working with data belonging to an area no longer than 6 squared kilometers.  As Chris W suggested, maybe the problem originated when I reprojected UTM 20S to WGS84. I did that by "saving as" and changing its SRC.  Then, with my shapefile in WGS84 y created a KML and a GPX.  Was my procedure ok?

Comment: @EvilGenius won't get notification of your comment unless you use th @ sign in front of the name (and no spaces), as I've just done (only works on one username per comment). I believe save-as is an appropriate way to do it in QGIS, and since they are on the same datum (WGS84) no transformation should be needed.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the amount of distortion you are seeing using WGS84 Zone 20S, taking measurements in southern South America (using ArcGIS). As @ChrisW stated, it sounds like you are saving it correctly.

Comment: @AndreJoost is there a way I can send you a 4 point sample shape and its KML?  I saved a new couple of data sets as to check once again and the distorsion contiunes.

Answer (score 2):

If your points are in UTM zone 20S, lat and lon should be swapped.

Reprojecting the coordinates to UTM 20S, I get the following x-y coordinates:

```
id;lat;long;x;y
1;-37,83722374;-61,82795608;603131;5811597
2;-37,83772773;-61,82861595;603072;5811542
3;-37,83767676;-61,82724009;603193;5811546
4;-37,83817749;-61,82789676;603135;5811492
```

The distance from one point to the next is 80.66 meters. If your original shapefile had coordinates of 100m distance, there must have something been wrong with the first reprojection you did.

Perhaps you should add the coordinates in the original projection too.