# Moving correctly projected features from ArcGIS Pro to UgCS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, wgs84, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Goal: get a 1/10 Nautical Mile radius circular feature (currently in NAD83/CA State Plane VI WKID:2230), in a .kml file, from ArcGIS Pro (3.1) into UgCS mission planning software (4.21.0) as an accurate representation of my FAA *Certificate of Waiver or Authorization* (COA) airspace without EPSG:3857 Web Mercator distortion.

Well, that’s what *I think* I want. Just when I think I understand coordinate reference systems…

I’ve received authorization from the FAA to fly a LiDAR mission in a controlled airspace. And that airspace is correctly delineated as a circle at a specific lat/long in ArcGIS Pro in a 2D map. But when I import the .kml from ArcGIS Pro (Layer to KML conversion tool) into either UgCS or Google Earth, I get an ellipse, longer along a line of longitude (longer along the Y axis).

Said another way: I think I need an ellipse that is precisely flattened along the along the Y axis, so that when projected in EPSG:3857, it will project correctly as a circle. This is what I need help with understanding/doing.

The answer to this post was useful in getting me to understand the problem:

[WGS84 geographic vs projected representation in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390353/wgs84-geographic-vs-projected-representation-in-arcgis-pro)

Comment: Your circle can't *look* like a circle in Web Mercator and be correct, anywhere, much less in the US.

Comment: I assumed that's what it was, but for some reason I didn't think the distortion would be so bad at 33 degrees north. Thanks for the response.