# Google Earth file export query

Tags: kml, export, google

Can anyone advise me if it is possible to nominate what format Google Earth exports it's .kml file in?

i.e. Can you export directly as a UTM file, DDD or DMS file somehow via a selection?  At this stage I have only been able to find that it only exports as DDD.

Comment: Note that KML by specification uses only a single projection, EPSG:4326. http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html

Comment: The format of KML is XML.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above - KML is an XML format and only uses a single projection (EPSG:4326) (see [What is the difference between WGS84 and EPSG4326?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/what-is-the-difference-between-wgs84-and-epsg4326))