# Same EPSG code for different objects

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I started recently working in a project where I need to start using EPSG codes to identify coordinate systems and their elements.

I saw that a single EPSG code can identify multiple objects. I am interpreting that each object must be from a different type (i.e., no two Datums can have the same EPSG code, but a Datum and a CRS can).

Am I correct with that assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, thanks to ycartwhelen I found the answer in the section 5.9 of [this document](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-1.pdf). Indeed, the codes are unique for each type. From the document:

> In the EPSG Dataset codes are assigned to CRSs, coordinate
>   transformations, and their component entities (datums, projections,
>   etc.).
>
> Within each entity type, every record has a unique code. Whilst
>   EPSG codes are unique within any one entity type, a code value may be
>   used for multiple entities of different types.

Answer (score 1):

The EPSG dataset describes coordinate reference systems (CRS), each of which are inherently affiliated with a datum.

You might find the answers to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/difference-between-wgs84-and-epsg4326) useful, in particular Dan S.'s answer.

[This document](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-1.pdf) published by the same organization in charge of EPSG goes into more depth. Specifically you might find sections 4.2 and 5.1 helpful.

Comment: EPSG doesn't just define CRS, it defines datums such as [WGS84](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:datum:EPSG::6326), units of measure such as [Arc Minute](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9103) etc